# Show full server name in command line

Tags: 12.04, command-line, putty

I have several servers that have the same prefix in their name: `mail.servername`. When I have several sessions open (I use PuTTY from Windows 7), it is a minor PITA to figure out which one is which since PuTTY names the windows `user@mail` and the command line displays `user@mail:~$` for all of them.

Is there a way to have the full server name displayed? I don't have the option of changing the servers' names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think what you are looking for for changing the PuTTY window title is this: `PuTTY allows the server to send xterm control sequences which modify the title of the window in mid-session.` From the [putty manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#4.8.3).

How to actually do it, point your favorite text editor to `~/.bashrc`
Locate the lines that say:

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Then change:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'
```

to:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@YOUR MODIFIED TINGY: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'
```

Save and be happy. If you wanna test it before doing the final change, use `export PS1='all the stuff'`

Comment: This worked, but I changed the `'` to `"` from your example (which you actually used in the first code block). Also, I just want to confirm that the line is supposed to end with `$` - I am suspicious whenever I see that as I worry it is from a copy & past out of a session, indicating the line goes beyond the window.

Comment: @Paul you shouldn't need to replace the single quote by a double one although that doesn't make a difference in that case. The last `$` is the standard non root user prompt, you should replace it by `#` if you are root. Usually, a space is following it for better readability but is missing here.

Comment: Thanks! I assume if I make the same change in `/root/.bashrc` the display will remain the same for `root` sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command

```
printf "\033]2;%s\a" $(</etc/hostname)
```

to have the server name displayed in the Putty window title bar.

Comment: `/etc/hostname` is the fqdn, which is reduced to `mail`. Pasting your command into a session does not seem to change anything.

Comment: Answer updated to use `/etc/hostname` instead of the `hostname` command

Comment: I tried using `/etc/hostname` and still nothing. The answer from Anders F. U. Kiær provides a more permanent solution and worked on the first try, but thank you for your response.

Comment: Are you sure the `/etc/hostname` file contains `mail.servername` and not just `mail` ? You can of course put this line in `.bashrc` for the name to be set automatically.

Comment: Yes, I checked before posting the comment (I'm just like that).

Comment: Then my suggestion should change the putty window title unless perhaps a putty setting forbids to change it but in that case, the accepted answer which just use the same technique wouldn't work either. The only slight difference is I'm using `]2;` (change window title) while Anders is using `]0;` (change window and icon title) but both are supported by putty, also I'm doing it once as the hostname isn't supposed to change often, while putting that command in the prompt will do it at every command.